# Baking temperature

Tags: baking, oven

My oven's max temperature is 200 degrees Celcius( 392 Fahrenheit). There are some baking recipes which ask for more than 392 F. How do I adjust the baking process then? Do I increase the baking time a little bit?

Comment: What type of oven do you have? It would also depend for what.

Comment: Thanks, My oven is the Samsung Smart Oven - MC32F606. Its a microwave and convention combo,with different functions of each.

Answer (score 5):

If the recipe calls for 400°F, the difference is just rounding error and the normal process of checking when it should be nearly done (say at 3/4 of the stated cooking time, or just before the minimum if a range) will be adequate.

If the recipe calls for up to about 425°F (220°C) it will take a little longer. Be sure not to open the oven door too soon (i.e. not before the stated time).

If the recipe calls for much hotter than that, the chances are that even with extending the cooking time you'll get a slightly different effect, such as less browning on top or a less crisp base and you may need to experiment.

Comment: Thanks Chris, I did do the maths and kind of increased the baking time for pizza which I made today. Came out pretty well. I guess one can play around with pizza but not sure about baking desserts since these would  need exact baking times and temperatures.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use the baking recipes which ask for more than 392°F. The temperature more than 392°F in some recipes is not required by chance, so if you will experiment and increase the time of baking instead of the temperature, you may be disappointed with the result.

There are so many good baking recipes on the Internet that don't ask for more than 392°F.Try to cook them.